# ASP.NET Core 2.1 Edit w/ Concatenated Primary Key

Tags: c#, crud, asp.net-core-2.1, composite-key

I'm a student using ASP.NET Core and related technologies for the first time. I've spent hours searching for a solution to this problem with no luck, so if anyone could help or point me at a tutorial to fix this, I would be very grateful.

My group and I are trying to build a web app to interface with an existing SQL database which has a lot of tables using concatenated primary keys. We can't change that. I used [this tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/797444/ASP-NET-MVC-Edit-Primary-Key-Values-for-Composite) to get our CRUD edit pages to even show, but if I try to submit any changes via that Edit page, I get an error like this:

> No webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:44311/GenCollectionSamplers/Edit

After some debugging, we're pretty sure this is a problem with **the POST Edit method in the Controller getting null IDs**, but we cannot figure out how to pass the correct IDs into the POST Edit method. The IDs are present in the GET Edit message.

Let me know if more code is needed.

Edit GET and POST from Controller:

```
// GET: GenCollectionSamplers/Edit/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(double? peopleID, double? colID)
    {
        if (peopleID == null || colID == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var genCollectionSamplers = await _context.GenCollectionSamplers.FindAsync(peopleID, colID);
        if (genCollectionSamplers == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        ViewData["FkPeopleId"] = new SelectList(_context.GenPeople, "PkPeopleId", "PkPeopleId", genCollectionSamplers.FkPeopleId);
        ViewData["FkCollectionId"] = new SelectList(_context.GenCollections, "CollectionId", "CollectionId", genCollectionSamplers.FkCollectionId);
        return View(genCollectionSamplers);
    }

    // POST: GenCollectionSamplers/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(double peopleID, double colID, [Bind("FkPeopleId,FkCollectionId")] GenCollectionSamplers genCollectionSamplers)
    {
        //Causes error because peopleID and colID are 0
        if (peopleID != genCollectionSamplers.FkPeopleId || colID != genCollectionSamplers.FkCollectionId)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                _context.Update(genCollectionSamplers);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!GenCollectionSamplersExists(genCollectionSamplers.FkPeopleId) || !GenCollectionSamplersExists(genCollectionSamplers.FkCollectionId))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        ViewData["FkPeopleId"] = new SelectList(_context.GenPeople, "PkPeopleId", "PkPeopleId", genCollectionSamplers.FkPeopleId);
        ViewData["FkCollectionId"] = new SelectList(_context.GenCollections, "CollectionId", "CollectionId", genCollectionSamplers.FkCollectionId);
        return View(genCollectionSamplers);
    }
```

Model:

```
public partial class GenCollectionSamplers
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Fk People Id")]
    public double FkPeopleId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Fk Collection Id")]
    public double FkCollectionId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Fk Collection")]
    public GenCollections FkCollection { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Fk People")]
    public GenPeople FkPeople { get; set; }
}
```

Edit view:

```
@model {path removed}.Models.GenCollectionSamplers

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

<h4>GenCollectionSamplers</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Edit">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="FkCollectionId" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="FkCollectionId" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="FkCollectionId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="FkPeopleId" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="FkPeopleId" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="FkPeopleId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="FkPeopleId" />
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="FkCollectionId" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Part of Index view:

```
<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => efModel.FkCollectionId)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => efModel.FkPeople)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FkCollection.CollectionId)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FkPeople.PkPeopleId)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { peopleID = item.FkPeopleId, colID = item.FkCollectionId }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { peopleID = item.FkPeopleId, colID = item.FkCollectionId }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { peopleID = item.FkPeopleId, colID = item.FkCollectionId })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have the hidden fields on your Edit view:?

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for="FkPeopleId" />
<input type="hidden" asp-for="FkCollectionId" /
```

It is this that gets bound to the Model when you submit the HttpPost and since they do not have any values assigned, you are getting 0. Get rid of these two hidden fields. The rendered page will create the hidden fields at run-time (inspect your rendered markup for Edit page) along with `__RequestVerificationToken` that knows which instance of this Model should be validated and then updated.

Comment: I left the hidden fields because of the tutorial I was referencing, but removing them does get rid of the "page not found" error on some of my models. Not all, though, and the ones that don't have the error end up with an invalid model state. I'll do some more debugging with the hidden fields removed tomorrow. Thanks for the suggestion!